# Click Facebook Login Button via X-Path

Tags: selenium, facebook, authentication

I have watched countless videos and have almost tried everything. I am automating a form using a selenium. I have all that set up, however, I need to first login and then fill out the form. For the life of me I cannot figure out how to click Facebook's login button using selenium. I have tried by x-path, by id, by text, by css selector. Can anyone help me? Here is what I have so far, but it says its invalid.

```html
#clicklogin
fblogin = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="u_0_d_3M"]')
fblogin.click()
```

Comment: You are aware that Facebook doesn't allow you to do that. Facebook only allow you to use the API. But if you are ok with getting banned go for it

Answer (score 1):

That button `id` looks to be dynamic.  Since there appears to be only 1 `button` element on that facebook.com page, try this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button").click()
```

Answer (score 0):

try more optimal code with `WebDriverWait`:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/")
login_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, "login")))
login_button.click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```